# How to deactivate Motoblur and undesirable services on Motorola Defy?

Tags: motoblur, motorola-defy

Is it possible to deactivate Motoblur sync and undesirable services on Motorola Defy like:

- `FeedRecieverService`
- `NewsRecieverService`
- `WeatherService`

(all lanched by `app.`)

Because I really don't care about Weather, news, feed, and must of all, I HATE this Motoblur account who "backup" my personal data without any possibility to limit him : It's just here, in the top of the synced accounts, with a little lock to the left...

If it's possible to do that without rooting the device or install a custom rom, it's for the best: I'm looking for the less intrusive method.

Thanks by advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way to deactivate Motoblur without rooting the phone!

1. Reset the phone to factory

   - `Settings` ⇒ `Privacy` or `SD and Storage` ⇒ `Factory data reset`
2. When the phone reboot, cancel the configuration of Motoblur
3. Take of the widget who remind you to configure it

And it's done !

Comment: How do you cancel the configuration of motoblur? It does not seem to be skip or cancable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember... maybe with home or back button...

Comment: While on the Setup screen, press Alt+E twice and then type "BLUROFF"  This should bypass the Setup Wizard and bring you straight to the Launcher.

Comment: I just configure another Defy, and you have a "Cancel" button when you start the configuration of Motoblur...

Answer (score 4):

You need root to do something like that, sorry to say.  Rooting is probably less intrusive than screwing with system services, though.

You could use [Titanium Backup](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-keramidas-titaniumbackup-xCzz.aspx) to "freeze" an app which will prevent if from running or being altered.  If that causes problems, you can simply unfreeze.

You could use [Autostarts](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-elsdoerfer-android-autostarts-jppi.aspx) to control what events trigger what services.  If a service is never triggered, it won't run!

Comment: Ok, so even if I root my phone, how can I stop Motoblur sync?

Comment: You should be able to freeze/uninstall it with TB.  If you still want the app but not the sync service (if that makes sense, I don't have a Motorola phone), then you can use Autostarts to change what events trigger the service -- remove it from all events.

Answer (score 1):

[Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=9456771) the device and **then flash a custom ROM**.  That will replace the Motoblur.  Once you are running the custom ROM, if you still see that these services are still running, since your phone is rooted you can uninstall the offending system apps.

Comment: And I don't know if a rootkit is hidden in the custom rom. I prefer Motoblur at this state...

Comment: I actually misread your question.  I will say I'm pretty confident that the major ROMs like CyanogenMod, are rootkit free.

Comment: What evidence do you have about this assertion? Everybody seems to be confident, but when I see how it's easy to hide some obfuscated code in Open Sources programs, I just don't see how you can be confident in those "borderline" peace of software without even accessing the code? (it's not a rhetorical question, I'm relay aware of it)

Comment: I don't have any evidence. I'm basing it on the fact that Cyanogenmod ROMs have been installed over 80K times.  Many of the people who use CM are developers/hackers or generally technically savvy & inquisitive tinkerers... People who closely monitor their processes, network traffic, performance... people who probably have hacked & modded CM themselves.  I feel ***pretty confident*** that of this sampling, if CM had an embedded rootkit, someone would have figured it out & the internet would be abuzz.

Comment: Also if a substantial botnet was created with Android phones its only a matter of time before the security world would be buzzing about this and we'd be hearing about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered a much easier method. Do a factory reset. then press the bottom left button, and select `Skip Setup`.